# The file '/Views/Home/Index.cshtml' has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested

Tags: azure

I have this project in windows Azure cloud. when i wanted to deploy the project in Staging, it threw me an error as "**The file '/Views/Home/Index.cshtml' has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested**". But it works fine in development machine. before i had this error there were few errors with Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll and msshrtmi.dll. But those were fixed by replacing the relevant files. Please help with any solution. I am stuck with this error more than a week.